# Imported Objects and UV Maps

Tags: uv, import

ok so here is what im trying to do, making a building with static props. while i was creating the props such as supports and so on, i started thinking about the uv map and about the major pain it was going to be managing the buildings geometry and the static props. A thought i had was that i could create the props outside of the current building file and import them in, but my question is, will they come into the file with their own UV map(where i can maintain the uv map only inside that file) and textured or will the model that is imported come into file expecting to be placed on the same uv map as the building.

Also to note, no i know that i could create the props outside and implement them into the building but what im trying to do is make a single object that all it needs to do is be placed and have all the props associated with it already placed

Answer (score 2):

When you import an object from another .blend file with Link or Append from the File menu, it comes with all linked datablocks, so UV maps, materials, textures, and various others will be also imported.

When you import from a different file format with File > Import, what you get depends on what the format stores. For example, "Wavefront (.obj)" can contain mesh, UV map, and texture, but not armature. When you import an SVG file, you will get several curve objects.

For an example of using multiple .blend files in a project, look at the [files](http://graphicall.org/bbb/index.php) from Big Buck Bunny.